# Magento 2: How to add fontawesome icons for each category top-menu item?

Tags: magento2, category, menu

I'm using Magento v2 and want to have icons added to the left side of each category menu item.
How can I accomplish this? I'm using a custom premium theme. When I try to see the template path by enabling template path hint, the category top-menu disappears! So I can not figure out the right template file to edit.
Is there anyone to tell me what's the right way to customize category template?
Thanks

Comment: Which Theme ur using?

Comment: Alothemes Electro